# Problem with dimensionality in Keras RNN - reshape isn't working?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Let's consider this random dataset on which I want to perform RNN:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
df_train = random.sample(range(1, 100), 50)
```

I want to apply RNN with lag equal to 1. I'll use my own function:

```
def create_dataset(dataset, lags):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(lags):
        subdata = dataset[i:len(dataset) - lags + i]
        dataX.append(subdata)
    dataY.append(dataset[lags:len(dataset)])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

which narrows dataframe with respect to number of lags. It outputs two numpy arrays - first is independent variables, and second one is dependent variable.

```
x_train, y_train = create_dataset(df_train, lags = 1)
```

But now when I'm trying to run the function:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=(1, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=SGD(lr = 0.1))
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

I obtain error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_18_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 49)
```

I've read about it and the solution is just to apply reshape:

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
```

but when I apply it I obtain error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_19_input to have shape (1, 1) but got array with shape (1, 49)
```

and I'm not sure where is the mistake. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling `lags` is called `look back` in literature. This technique allow to feed the RNN with more contextual data and learn mid/long range dependencies.

The error is telling you that you are feeding the layer (shape: `1x1`) with the dataset (shape: `1x49`)

There are 2 reasons behind the error:

1. The first is due to your `create_dataset` which is building a stack of `1x(50 - lags) = 1x49` vectors, which is the opposite of what you want `1x(lags) = 1x1`.

   In particular this line is the responsible:

```
subdata = dataset[i:len(dataset) - lags + i]

# with lags = 1 you have just one
# iteration in range(1): i = 0
subdata = dataset[0:50 - 1 + 0]
subdata = dataset[0:49] # which is a 1x49 vector

# In order to create the right vector
# you need to change your function:

def create_dataset(dataset, lags = 1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    # iterate to a max of (50 - lags - 1) times
    # because we need "lags" element in each vector
    for i in range(len(dataset) - lags - 1):
        # get "lags" elements from the dataset
        subdata = dataset[i:i + lags]
        dataX.append(subdata)
        # get only the last label representing
        # the current element iteration
        dataY.append(dataset[i + lags])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

2. If you use `look back` in your RNN you also need to increase the input dimensions, because you are looking also at precendent samples.

   The network indeed is looking to more data than just 1 sample, because it needs to "look back" to more samples to understand mid/long range dependencies.

   This is more conceptual than actual, in your code is fine because `lags = 1`:

```
model.add(SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=(1, 1)))

# you should use lags in the input shape
model.add(SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=(1, LAGS)))
```